# What is the conjunctive normal form for $(\neg Q\land P) \lor (\neg Q\land R) \lor (\neg P \land \neg R)$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, conjunctive-normal-form

$(\neg Q\land P) \lor  (\neg Q\land R) \lor (\neg P \land \neg R)$ 
i have calculated this using wolframalpha and the output of CNF was 
 $(\neg Q \lor\neg P) \land  (\neg Q \lor\neg R) $ 
but all i can reach out -after using the **Absorption rule**- is $(\neg Q\land P) \lor  (\neg Q\land R) \lor (\neg P \land \neg R)$ and using **Distribution**  the final result is $\neg Q\land(R \lor P)\lor \neg P \land \neg R $ 
 so can someone help me getting what is wrong

Comment: Your formula is equivalent, but it is not the conjunctive normal form.

Comment: what is wrong is you can't have $\color{red}{∨}$ here for CNF. $$¬Q∧(R∨P)\color{red}{∨}(¬P∧¬R)$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Redundacy Law or Reduction might be useful here
$\def\box#1#2{\boxed{\underline{\text{#1}}\\#2\\}}$
$$\box{The Redundancy Law/Reduction}
{(P\land \neg Q)\lor Q\equiv P\lor Q\\
\underline{\text{Proof.}}\\
\begin{align}
&(P\land \neg Q)\lor Q\\
\equiv&(P\lor Q)\land (\neg Q\lor Q)\hspace{5ex}\text{Distributive law}\\
\equiv&(P\lor Q)\land \top\hspace{13ex}\text{Negation law}\\
\equiv&P\lor Q\hspace{19.3ex}\text{Identity law}
\end{align}
}$$
Here is a possible approach for your question, which gives the Minimal CNF
\begin{align}
&(¬Q∧P)∨(¬Q∧R)∨(¬P∧¬R)\\
\equiv&(\neg Q\land(P\lor R))∨(¬P∧¬R)\tag*{Distributive law}\\
\equiv&(\neg Q\land\neg(\neg P\land\neg R))∨(¬P∧¬R)\tag*{De Morgan's law}\\
\equiv&\neg Q\lor (\neg P\land \neg R)\tag*{Redundancy law}\\
\equiv&(\neg Q\lor \neg P)\land(\neg Q\lor\neg R)\tag*{Distributive law}
\end{align}